# Перебор имён столбцов бд через переменную php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! 
Как можно передать в запрос в имя столбца переменную? Хочу получить примерно такой код:

```
$query='SELECT time_"'.$id.'" FROM days_time';
```

Comment: Почти так, только кавычки не нужны `$query='SELECT time_'.$id.' FROM days_time';`

Comment: А что мешает получить такой код? Разъясните свой вопрос, он немоного не понятен

Comment: Ничего кроме моей глупости, немного исправил  код и получил что хотел:    $str="time_".$id;

  
       $query='SELECT "'.$str.'" FROM days_time';